# Is it a good practice to pass IQueryable as parameter in a Service layer method?

Tags: asp.net, parameters, filter, iqueryable, service-layer

I have an ASP.NET application with 3 layers **UI**, **Service Layer** and **Repository**.

I have to implement a **search functionality** on the products in the database. 
`ProductRepository` is my **repository class** and the signature of the method that gets all the **products** from the database is:

```
IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts();
```

Therefore from my **Service Layer** I use:

```
IProductRepository _ProductRepository = new ProductRepository(); 

IQueryable<Product> products = _ProductRepository.GetAllProducts();
```

If I would like to filter `IQueryable<Product> products`, for instance by taking those product with **price > 100** or just those with **color = "yellow"**.

So I was wondering, instead of creating methods in `ProductRepository` such as:

```
IQueryable<Product> GetAllProductsByColor(int colorId)
```

I was wondering if it is a good practice to create in my **Service Layer** a set of methods that accept `IQueryable<Product>` as parameter and perform the filtering directly there:

```
IQueryable<Product> FilterProducts(IQueryable<Product> products, Dictionary<string, object> filters)
```

Where `Dictionary<string, string>` represent a set with **(propertyName, value)**.

The advantage of this solution is that if I have to apply multiple filters I just pass the `IQueryable<Product>` already filtered, instead of taking everytime the intersection between the filtered product sets.

Is it a good practice (as long as I keep the **context open**) or it is not "allowed"by the multi-layered architecure pattern?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends on what provides the implementation of your IQueryable. In most cases, you run the risk of allowing users of your IQueryable to either 1) filter on fields that are not indexed (thus hosing the database layer, if you have any, when you have large tables), or 2) execute arbitrary IQueryable operations that put a huge load on the database (such as GroupBy's, Join's, etc.).

Assuming you are OK with 1, in order to prevent 2) I usually allow users to load objects through a `IEnumerable<Product> LoadProducts(Predicate<Product> filter)` method which I then transform into a `Where` on the IQueryable; this hides the other IQueryable methods and yet allows full flexibility for filtering purposes only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I always return IQueryable from the Repository in order to allow deferred execution. My Service Layer returns always IEnumerable. May you explain with some example your techinique with Predicate<T>?

Comment: Assume you have the following method: `IEnumerable<Product> LoadProducts(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter)`, then you can implement it as `return myQueryable.Where<Product>(filter)` and you can call it with a lambda-expression: `IEnumerable<Product> results = LoadProducts(p => p.Color == Colors.Red)`